# How do I do this date calculation?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in my table called `expiry_date`. I am using the following query to return this date, plus 6 months:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(expiry_date, INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AS expiry_date;
```

I would like to modify the above so that if `expiry_date` plus 6 months is in the past (before `CURRENT_DATE`), a further 6 months is added as many times as necessary, until the date is in the future.

How can I do this using MySQL?

Comment: What format is `expiry_date` in?

Comment: @MyStream: It's a `DATE` field

Comment: Please don't tag your titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First approach:

```
SELECT 
   case when expiry_date > SYSDATE() then
       DATE_ADD(   expiry_date  , INTERVAL 6 MONTH) 
   else
       DATE_ADD(
          DATE_SUB( 
             SYSDATE(),   
             INTERVAL 
             ( DATEDIFF( SYSDATE(), expiry_date )  % ( 6 * 30) )  
             MONTH
          )
          , 
          INTERVAL 6 MONTH) 
   end
   AS expiry_date
FROM ...
```

not tested.

Comment: Would the 30 day value here work as accurately as a calculated INTERVAL value? (I don't know the difference - asking for clarity.)

Comment: No, this answer is actually wrong. Depending on the date it would give 5, 6 or 7 months added.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested this with the following data:

```
Table: `test`
uid      expiry_date
1        2011-11-03
2        2011-01-20
```

Code:

```
SELECT 
    `uid`,
    `expiry_date`,
    PERIOD_DIFF(
        date_format(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY),'%Y%m'),
        date_format(`expiry_date`,'%Y%m')
    ) as `dif`, /* Straight Month Difference */
    CEIL(PERIOD_DIFF(
        date_format(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY),'%Y%m'),
        date_format(`expiry_date`,'%Y%m')
    )/6) AS `dif2`, /* How many blocks of 6 months, rounded up */
    (
        IF(
            ( /* If 1 block is > today, add the 6 months and finish */
            DATE_ADD(
                CURDATE(),
                INTERVAL 1 DAY
            ) < DATE_ADD(
                `tOuter`.`expiry_date`,
                INTERVAL 6 MONTH
            )
        ), /* this is with just 6 months added */
        DATE_ADD(
            `tOuter`.`expiry_date`,
                INTERVAL 6 MONTH
            ), /* this works out how many blocks of 6 months to add */
            DATE_ADD(
                `tOuter`.`expiry_date`,
            INTERVAL (
                6 * CEIL( /* round up number of months */
                    PERIOD_DIFF( /* get number of months */
                        date_format(
                            DATE_ADD(
                                CURDATE(),
                                INTERVAL 1 DAY
                            ),
                            '%Y%m'
                        ),
                        date_format(
                            `expiry_date`,
                            '%Y%m'
                        )
                    )/6 /* divide months by 6 to match question */
                )
            ) MONTH /* add the dynamically calculated interval */
        )
    )
) AS `expiry_date_calculated` FROM `test` AS `tOuter`
```

It results in:

```
uid     expiry_date      dif         dif2       expired_date_calculated
1       2011-11-03       0           0          2012-05-03
2       3011-01-20       10          2          2012-01-20
```

Is this the desired output for this input?

**PERFORMANCE NOTE**: This is abysmal in performance and I invite others to suggest a more efficient routine. This might be better written as a stored procedure and definitely better if you passed in the date for CURDATE() as a string.

Example: with 2 fields, it takes 0.04 seconds to produce the desired results above.

**EDIT**: Smaller Version:

```
SELECT 
 `id`, `expiry_date`,
 (IF((DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) < DATE_ADD(`expiry_date`,INTERVAL 6 MONTH)),
   DATE_ADD(`expiry_date`,INTERVAL 6 MONTH),
   DATE_ADD(`expiry_date`,
    INTERVAL (6 * CEIL(PERIOD_DIFF(
        date_format(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY),'%Y%m'),
        date_format(`expiry_date`,'%Y%m')
    )/6)) MONTH
   )
 )
) AS `expiry_date_calculated`
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add either **X years and 6 months** or **X years and 12 months** to you expiry_date. X is the difference between they year part off now() and expiry_date.

```
select if(dayofyear(expiry_date)>=dayofyear(now()), 
 date_add(test, interval concat(year(now())-year(expiry_date), '-6') year_month), 
 date_add(test, interval concat(year(now())-year(expiry_date), '-12') year_month)) 
as expiry_date from <table>;
```

One example. expiry_date is 2009-10-01

dayofyear(expiry_date) is 274

dayofyear(now()) is 325

so the first condition is false. `concat(year(now())-year(expiry_date), '-12'` gives 2011-2009=2 years and 12 months (the string is '2-12') and that is used in `date_add('2009-10-01', interval '2-12' year_month` which is 2011-10-01 + 6 months = 2012-05-01.

Comment: This would only work for 2 intervals of 6 months, and I think the poster is looking for something that could be a variable number of intervals.

Comment: My query will always return a value that is in the future and always a multiple of 6 months from the initial value. I think that is what the poster wants :) Note the "X years" part.

Comment: Ah - very nice :) Just re-read it - succinct.  If my answer is upvoted, please upvote this answer as it's more succinct and probably more efficient.

Comment: Thanks. It ended up pretty clean.